# What is UI Bootstrap and what is its purpose?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Started a project with Bootstrap 3(http://getbootstrap.com/) and now I just came accross this UI Bootstrap(https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). It says -Bootstrap components written in pure AngularJS by the AngularUI Team.

I did not understand this. Is this completely differnt from BootStrap 3? And in the Getting Started Section of UI Bootstrap(https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), it says the dependences are

- AngularJS (requires AngularJS 1.3.x, tested with 1.4.7). 0.12.0 is
  the last version of this library that supports AngularJS 1.2.x.
- Bootstrap CSS (tested with version 3.1.1). This version of the
  library (0.14.2) works only with Bootstrap CSS in version 3.x. 0.8.0
  is the last version of this library that supports Bootstrap CSS in
  version 2.3.x.

Can someone please throw some light as to what the purpose of UI Bootstrap

Is this an alternative to the Bootstrap 3, or a supliment? Strangely I did find any such info at UI Bootstrap's site.

Comment: Are you developing an angular app?

Comment: It basically implements bootstrap's components in AngularJS instead of jQuery. so u can use bootstrap design and components without dealing with jQuery

Comment: I am developing an asp.net mvc + web api app. Front end Bootstrap 3 + angularJs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-correctly-use-bootstrapjs-and-angularjs-together

Basically, UI bootstrap is bootstrap without jquery (and with angular), so the overall library size is reduced. The functionality is limited as compared to twitter bootstrap.